# My ListView is not scrollable. I have used coordinate layout

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a nav drawer with 2 more fragments. One fragment has a list view but the listview is not getting scrolled.I'm getting data but only thing is listview is not allowing to scroll down.

activity_main

```
            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/Shitstuff"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            android:layout_marginTop="-24dp">
            </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
            </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

ListView

```
            <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".FragmentA">

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:divider="#020202"
                    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />

            </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please find the image link : http://postimg.org/image/6gvifajnd/

Comment: I'm getting only first 7 records.. but the url has about 118 jsonArrays..

Comment: use nested scroll with pagination or just use nested scroll it looks like your are able to scroll down even your all data is shown

Comment: I have added android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" in ListView but still I'm unable to scroll down..

Comment: but one more thing nested scrolling will work only for lollipop or above

Comment: check this out https://pristalovpavel.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/doing-it-right-vertical-scrollview-with-viewpager-and-listview/

Comment: try putting your viewpager inside <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView ...>
    <LinearLayout ...>
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

Comment: @Madhur : Sir, Are you sure that it works only on lollipop. Because I tried testing on Nexus 5 API23 & Samsung Galaxy API 16. It worked fine. And I have also tried on API 19 on Genymotion. I haven't faced any issue.
Let me know your thoughts.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After doing some trail and errors I found a fix..Not sure if it is a right way of doing it or not..But still posting the activity_main layout file.
Just compare both activity_main layout files. I have made some changes to it.

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerView">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

            </FrameLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#FFDD00"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:background="#FFDD00"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/Shitstuff"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            android:layout_marginTop="-24dp">

            </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
            </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: the list scrolls but the tablayout hides some part of the layout